# Swift display previous entered item in array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, sorting, core-data

I am trying to display the pervious entered exercise attributes in the current workout. If I go to the pervious workout everything shows up but when I go to my current workout the previous exercise attributes don't show and the date label only shows today's date and not the previous workout date. Here are the two functions for the issue. Let me know if i need to post more.

```
 func lastWorkout() -> Workout? {
    if let client = currentClient(), let currentWorkout = currentWorkout(), let workouts = client.workouts as? Set<Workout> {
        // get all this client's workouts in cronological order
        let sortedWorkouts = workouts.sorted { (one, two) -> Bool in
            let scheduledTimeOfOne = one.appointment?.scheduled ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
            let scheduledTimeOfTwo = two.appointment?.scheduled ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
            return scheduledTimeOfOne > scheduledTimeOfTwo
        }
        // get the index of this workout
        let indexOfTodaysWorkout = sortedWorkouts.index(of: currentWorkout) ?? 0
        // go back one workout to find the last workout completed
        let lastWorkout: Workout? = (indexOfTodaysWorkout - 1) < 0 ? nil : sortedWorkouts[indexOfTodaysWorkout - 1]
        // and return
        return lastWorkout
    }
    return nil
}

/// Last Exercise Info to load previous exercise data
func lastExercise() -> Exercise? {
    guard let selectedExercise = currentExerciseInfo() else{
        return nil
    }
    if let exercises = lastWorkout()?.exercises as? Set<Exercise>, let pastExercise = exercises.first(where: { $0.exerciseInfo == selectedExercise }) {
        return pastExercise
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Let us know for when it works and when it does not, do you return `nil` from any of these methods and if so, when...

Comment: It returns nil when opening the current workout

Comment: Then just check why it returns nil, is the Set empty or are you doing something else wrong...

Comment: its coming up nil but i know there are is data to display

Comment: `Workout` is coming up nil or `Exercise`?

Comment: What is the `Workout` type? What about the `Exercise`  type? What do your `currentClient()` and `currentWorkout()` methods do?

Comment: Are you using HealthKit? If so you should add that tag to your question.

Comment: I am not using HealthKit. Workout is what is coming up nil

Answer (score 0):

So the array count was off in last workout function. Here is what the working function looks like. I am still not displaying the proper date. it just gives today's date.

```
func lastWorkout() -> Workout? {
    if let client = currentClient(), let currentWorkout = currentWorkout(), let workouts = client.workouts as? Set<Workout> {
        // get all this client's workouts in cronological order
        let sortedWorkouts = workouts.sorted { (one, two) -> Bool in
            let scheduledTimeOfOne = one.appointment?.scheduled ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
            let scheduledTimeOfTwo = two.appointment?.scheduled ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
            return scheduledTimeOfOne > scheduledTimeOfTwo
        }
        // get the index of this workout
        let indexOfTodaysWorkout = sortedWorkouts.index(of: currentWorkout) ?? 0
        // go back one workout to find the last workout completed
        let lastWorkout: Workout? = sortedWorkouts.count < 2 ? nil : sortedWorkouts[indexOfTodaysWorkout + 1]
        // and return
        return lastWorkout
    }
    return nil
}
```